# Select class from component with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two instances of a component on my page and I need to select it's class to do a css transform, it works but the problem is that the first instance is the only one that is being triggered.

```
const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel-slide");
carousel.style.transform = `translateX(-100%)`;
```

When I click a button my carousel should go next, but I'm always selecting the first `.carousel-slide` so even if I click the next button on the second instance of my component, the first instance is the one that is being affected

Comment: Why are you manipulating raw DOM in react? Have you tried setting style on the component?

Comment: @Drew Reese it's a carousel, there's a next button that when clicked the carousel should move.

Comment: React has several ways to set the style on components being rendered, but generally speaking, direct DOM manipulation is a react anti-pattern.

Comment: so what's the correct way? based on my situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers for you:

1. You may not need to do this at the DOM level.
2. If you do, you use "refs"

### You may not need to do this at the DOM level

From [Style and CSS - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#can-i-do-animations-in-react):

> React can be used to power animations. See [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/) and [React Motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion) or [React Spring](https://github.com/react-spring/react-spring), for example.

Here's an example of adding a class to trigger a (very boring) transform:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            transformed: false
        };
        this.triggerTransform = this.triggerTransform.bind(this);
    }

    triggerTransform() {
        this.setState({transformed: true});
    }

    render() {
        const {transformed} = this.state;
        return <div className={transformed ? "transformed" : undefined} onClick={this.triggerTransform}>Click me</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.transformed {
    transform: translateX(+10%);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### But if you do (or want to)...

...you use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) for those occasions where you need to cross the React/DOM boundary like that.

1. Create a ref
2. Use it on the JSX defining the element you want to target
3. Use the ref's `current` property when you need to do something on the actual DOM element

Rough example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
        this.triggerTransform = this.triggerTransform.bind(this);
    }

    triggerTransform() {
        if (this.myRef.current) {
            this.myRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(+10%)`
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div ref={this.myRef} onClick={this.triggerTransform}>Click me</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.11.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

Both of the above can be done with hooks as well, you don't need to be using class components. For some reason I had the impression the OP was using class components, but...I think I invented that.